How is my VBA formula to change the bar chart formula to have dynamic ranges and labels wrong?
how i can change bar chart formula to have dynamic ranges and labels?
I have this command:
Sheets("panel").ChartObjects("Wykres2").Chart.SeriesCollection("f syg").Formula = _
   "=SERIES("fsyg";"panel!$N$3:N" & (zera/2) + 2;"panel!$K$3:K" & (zera/2) + 2;1)"

With ranges made like i did with changing range values:
Range("panel!$I" & 3 + okno & ":I" & zera + 2).Value = "0"

I excel chart formula is like this:
=SERIES("f syg";panel!$N$3:$N$300;panel!$K$3:$K$300;1)
It shows me syntax error. I tried diffrent changes, like removing, replacing " in range, but it didn't worked.
EDIT:
I tried another way:
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set cht = ws.ChartObjects(2).Chart
For Each srs In cht.SeriesCollection
    srs.Delete
Next

Set srs = cht.NewSeries
With srs
    .CategoryNames = Range("panel!N3:N" & (zera / 2) + 2)
    .Values = Range("panel!K3:K" & (zera / 2) + 2)

But it show error: Object doesn't support this property or method (Error 438).
Values are y and CategoryNames are x in Bar chart?

When assigning a formula in VBA you typically need to use a comma separator and not your local ;  Also, and double quotes inside the formula string need to be escaped by doubling them up.

When assigning a formula in VBA you typically need to use a comma separator and not your local ; Also, and double quotes inside the formula string need to be escaped by doubling them up.
Try something like (breaking that long line up a little for easier debugging):
Sub Tester()

    Dim s As Series, ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, zera As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("panel")
    
    Set s = ws.ChartObjects("Wykres2").Chart.SeriesCollection("f syg")
    
    zera = 20 'for example
    lr = (zera / 2) + 2
    
    'option 1: use the SERIES formula
    s.Formula = Replace("=SERIES(""fsyg"",panel!N3:N<lr>,panel!K3:K<lr>,1)", "<lr>", lr)
    
    'option2: update the properties separately
    s.Name = "fsyg"
    s.XValues = ws.Range("N3:N" & lr)
    s.Values = ws.Range("K3:K" & lr)
    
End Sub

When working in VBA though, it's typically easier to modify the series properties directly (option 2 above), rather than updating them via the SERIES formula (option 1).

I tried it and it shows run-time error 5: invalid procedure call or argument.

Works for me, but my formula separator is comma.  Try with your original semicolon.

Does (zera / 2) + 2 evaluate to a whole number?

...Series also has FormulaLocal though, so my comma above is likely OK here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.series.formulalocal

Yes zera is whole number.

A whole even number?

Yes it is fourier transform range that have to be 2^n.

See edits above - try the "option2" approach.  I think it's much easier to debug compared to using SERIES()
